# How to write text with only 5 buttons?

Tags: controls, text-editor

I have a text field in which I can write lower case and upper case letters, numbers and some special characters (' ', '-', '_', '/', '.'). I have only 1 button that can be pressed right, left, up, down and center.

What would be the best way given the buttons that I have to allow writing text?

- use left right to go through the letters of the sentence, up down to cycle between characters (a, b..) and click to change mode (between lower case, upper case, number and special characters), but I don't really know how to remove characters with this way, other than to replace them with spaces ( or use a special character that is delete )
- same as number 1 but if I have more than 1 space remove the extra spaces, and leave only 1
- use left right to go through the letters of the sentence, up to cycle between characters, down to remove and click to change between modes.
- Any other idea?

**Edit:**

The length of the text is of maximum 120 characters, and all types of characters are needed.

Comment: Is the button analog or digital? (Are up, down, left, and right the only directions that register, or can you roll it around in a circle?) What sort of screen is available? Can it show more than the text field?

Comment: Digital, can't roll it around. I have space on screen to show a table of letters or something like that, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: How much text will need to be written? Are users typing their name, a tweet, or a novel? Are lowercase letters absolutely vital?

Comment: I edited my question, and added the maximum length.

Comment: Surely this problem has been looked into by game designers at some point?
I can think of a lot of different examples from games- left to right scrolling alphabet high score entry, terrible and annoying overly sensitive fields where you only see the currently highlighted letter, RPG typical whole alphabet select boxes...
It is this latter one which seems to have lasted the test of time actually. It is still seen rather a lot, even on the ps3's web browser. The others...not so much.

Comment: Perhaps holding the click will toggle it into delete/backspace mode? Not entirely intuitive but there doesn't appear to be many options.

Comment: @DasBeasto I have thought about this too, but as you said it is not very intuitive and was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: @theotherone I don't really want to have a whole alphabet text box, I would prefer a solution using only the buttons and the text box, but if there isn't a clear way of doing it, I will consider this.

Comment: You could use 4 of the buttons to navigate on an virtual keyboard and use the middle button to confirm. So you basically use it like arrow keys on an regular keyboard. Another aproch is that you group the buttons and the them let the user select between the groups. So when I want to type something a Window opens that lets me decide between the numbers and 3 other groups. I select the numbers. Then I can choose between 1234, 5678 and so on. I choose 1234. Then i can choose between 1 2 3 or 4. I chose 3. This method is faster because you need to press less buttons.

Comment: Both are uncommon bit I personally would go for the approch with the grouping because it allows the user quicker typing and also habitualization because the starting point never changes (If the user gets to a keyboard position using the arrow method instated the user would have an diffrent starting position which makes habitualization more difficult for the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are going to need a virtual on-screen keyboard because of the volume of text, the need for upper and lower case letters, and if users will typing frequently.**

Using only a single button to cycle through letters is crippling, and will result in a lot of frustration if you miss a letter and have to loop back around. Similarly, having to find the blank space character to delete a mistake is going to be hard, and you will probably have to explain that somewhere.

A 120 character limit is about a sentence or two, so users will need to be able to see the entirety of what they've typed rather than only the nearest couple characters. It's easy to make mistakes when focusing on only a letter at a time. ("Am I at the 2nd or 3rd 'i' in Mississippi?") Adding in the need for upper and lower case letters along with numbers and symbols, and you also need a way to indicate what mode you are in. Lastly, if users need to use this interface more than once per month you want to avoid as many annoyances as possible. (Less frequent use can tolerate a higher level of frustration.)

Most video game consoles have similar limitations (directional movement instead of a full keyboard), and they solve the problem with an on-screen virtual keyboard. Users navigate the letters with directional buttons and select them with another button.

PS3 Virtual Keyboard from http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/basicoperations/keyboard.html

[image: PS3 Virtual Keyboard]

Xbox 360 Virtual Keyboard from http://www.groovypost.com/howto/xbox-360-set-up-use-twitter/

[image: Xbox 360 Virtual Keyboard]

I tend to prefer the PS3 keyboard because it uses a QWERTY layout by default, and has a place for dictionary suggestions to speed up the input. (Alphabetic order should be avoided because users don't know where the breaks in each line occur, and most have experience with standard QWERTY.) Both Xbox and PS3 virtual keyboards have shortcuts that use additional buttons on their controllers, but those are optional.

In your scenario, you would probably want to have a click of the main button be used for selecting a letter. (This heavily depends on how easy it is to click the button **without** triggering one of the directions.)

*If use of a screen is not practical, or the button input is too imprecise to spell things accurately, it may still be possible to do what you need.*

- Alter the visual style of the text field so that it does not resemble one they would see in a web browser. This includes use of a monospaced font, and removing the standard text cursor ( | ).
- Use up and down to cycle through the letters. Draw arrows above and below the currently active letter to indicate how to select a different character.
- Use left as backspace, and don't have a movable cursor. Input always occurs at the end of the text.
- Use right to save the current letter and move to the next. Each new letter should start with the blank space character, or 'A' as long as users can scroll down to get to the space.
- Clicking the center button changes the mode. Show this mode on the screen somewhere.

This should allow basic text entry without making mistakes overly punishing. Users will want to type as little as possible, though, so expect lots of abbreviations and improper capitalization.

Comment: This looks similar to the Roku keyboard. I agree that this is the way to go, and I'll add that it's a huge pain in the neck, even for short text entries. So, @N Alex, pre-populate and auto-fill if you can.

Comment: I think I will go without the keyboard. The users will use this input rarely, and doesn't really matter what they input as long as they can associate it with a place and a radio frequency.

Comment: I've used systems with the left/right = position, up/down = character before, mostly in naming synthesiser patches. For me this is also an unusual activity but it also engenders so much frustration that I am often reluctant to a) purchase systems that use this method or b) complete the task more than once or twice - The level of frustration that this UI creates is far greater than you can imagine!

Comment: @AndrewMartin Yes, I understand that it's frustrating to use something like this to input text, but for what I developed, users will also be able to attach a keyboard if they don't want to use this system.